# SXSSFWorkbook OutOfMemoryException GC overhead on 26MB file

Tags: java, excel, garbage-collection, apache-poi, out-of-memory

I have an excel file which serves as template for my program. This template file is around 26MB in size. I try to open the file for write access with this code:

```
Workbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(new XSSFWorkbook(new File(getClass().getResource(TEMPLATE_PATH).getFile())),
                100, true, true);
```

This however causes the following exception:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded    at
>   org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Cur$CurLoadContext.attr(Cur.java:3039)
>     at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.loadNode(Locale.java:1433)
>     at
>   org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.loadNodeChildren(Locale.java:1396)
>     at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.loadNode(Locale.java:1438)
>     at
>   org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.loadNodeChildren(Locale.java:1396)
>     at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.loadNode(Locale.java:1438)
>     at
>   org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.loadNodeChildren(Locale.java:1396)
>     at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.loadNode(Locale.java:1438)
>     at
>   org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:1378)
>     at
>   org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:1363)
>     at
>   org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderBase.parse(SchemaTypeLoaderBase.java:370)
>     at org.apache.poi.POIXMLTypeLoader.parse(POIXMLTypeLoader.java:164)
>     at
>   org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.WorksheetDocument$Factory.parse(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.read(XSSFSheet.java:226)  at
>   org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.onDocumentRead(XSSFSheet.java:218)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.parseSheet(XSSFWorkbook.java:443)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.onDocumentRead(XSSFWorkbook.java:408)
>     at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:169)  at
>   org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.(XSSFWorkbook.java:270)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.(XSSFWorkbook.java:323)
>     at
>   com.company.project.writer.excel.AirlinesMasterWriter.(AirlinesMasterWriter.java:70)
>     at
>   com.company.project.business.controller.impl.DiioBCImpl.writeAirlinesMasterFile(DiioBCImpl.java:141)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:280)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)

**What is the right way to write to such big excel files with apache poi?**

---

Please note that I fetch all the data I need to write to the template before opening the template. The size of the data is no more than 300MB, more likely less. Also note that the rest of my code works fine if I create a new `SXSSFWorkbook` instead of opening the existing.

Comment: Did you try to increase your heap size?

Comment: @Selaron I tried with `-Xmx6g` and it did nothing (I verified that this command worked by looking at RAM usage via Task Manager). I also tried with `-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit` but then it only ran forever but nothing else happened

Comment: It’s great that you are trying to use `SXSSFWorkbook` for writing, but that doesn’t help when you construct an `XSSFWorkbook` first. The stack trace clearly shows that it is the construction of the latter which fails. Which doesn’t come at a surprise, as the `XSSFWorkbook` is horribly inefficient.

Comment: @Holger that is the only way I found to pass any existing file to `SXSSFWorkbook`. Did I miss any way?

Comment: I’m afraid, you didn’t miss anything. Combining the streaming writer with an existing template seems only to work this way, in other words, only with very small templates. I don’t know of any POI solution (and no alternative either). I have no idea why the POI team is happy with that insane memory consumption.

Comment: @Holger Memory is cheap these days, and programmers are expensive... If you fancy shelling out for the many-many-person-months of coding time required to re-implement core parts of POI with super memory efficient code, the dev list would love to hear about your generousity!

Comment: @AxelRichter with “no alternative”, I meant, no similar Java library. Of course, there *are* alternatives. E.g., we wrote our own loader for the data, we’re interested in. But that might not fit for the OP. Further, you could convert the `xslx` file to an `xsl` file and use the old POI API. As the POI for the old binary formats is a really good piece of software. For equivalent files, it will only need a fraction of the memory. This demonstrates that there is no technical need to fill gigabytes of heap memory for these data, but you can’t create xlsx files, which is what the OP wants to do.

Comment: @Gagravarr sure, memory is cheap. But when you need hundreds of gigabytes to load a single xlsx file, there might be the problem that your computer does not support this amount of memory. And the POI developers recognized the problem, as they created the streaming alternative. Something that was never needed for the old `HSSFWorkbook`.

Comment: @AxelRichter read my comment correctly. “*For equivalent files*, it will only need a fraction of the memory.” Of course, we’re talking about files with the same properties. If `XSSFWorkbook` needs several gigabytes to load a file with significantly less than 65,535 rows per sheet, we would not even dare to try loading a workbook having more rows with that library… And I don’t know, what this discussion is heading at. The OP couldn’t load a 300MB file with 6GB heap and the bad message is, with POI, even doubling or quadrupling the heap memory might not help and there is no solution.

Comment: I guess my best bet for a fast result is to try to split the template into multiple parts and have the end user merge them manually

Comment: @XtremeBaumer: If you could providing your template file having around 26 MB in size somewhere for downloading and would tell in your question where the bulk content then shall be streamed in, then I am sure I can show you a way to do so. ...either using `SXSSF` or streaming in the sheet's `XML` directly. But as general as the question is until now, it is not answerable.

Comment: I am sorry, but that is not possible, as I don't own the template. Anyways, thanks for the offer

Comment: @AxelRichter If it would help you enough, I can provide a pdetailed description of the areas I need to write to. My only problem right now is that I can't open the template with apache poi

Comment: "I can't open the template with apache poi": Yes. And yes, that `XSSFWorkbook` has problems in memory consumption is known. So in general the answer is: forget it. In special it depends on the kind of template whether there are other solutions. So for providing a solution I would need the template together with the description to where the bulk content shall be streamed into that template. Maybe you can anonymizing the template. But, if you do that, then try after that whether the problem nor occurs using the anonymized template.

Comment: I just realized that the bulk of the size actually comes from all the styles and by far not from the data that is already written in it. 1 sheet has actually around 3MB just styles.

Comment: `*g*` Yes, I know those office workers who better would have become painters. The main criterion for a sheet: It should be colorful. And ranges of cells having the same format? Why? Much better is a sparkling mix of cells containig text, prices, percents, dates wildly messed up. Don't let those office workers creating templates.

Comment: Yeah, sadly. But more sadly is that I have to use this template. As there seems to be no way to solve this question, I'd suggest to close it

Comment: @AxelRichter you mean, like [this one](https://media.licdn.com/media-proxy/ext?w=800&h=800&hash=7ilvS1X8uGI03NSWkKldaa0rsiw%3D&ora=1%2CaFBCTXdkRmpGL2lvQUFBPQ%2CxAVta5g-0R6nlh8Tw1It6a2FowGz60oISIfYC2G8G2f1spyfNT-tdoDSeLChpEtOdSoDmBJkcrG-GGGiSp75LfC3eZRz-OW8TZniVQ9VWiwMo0Ft-YE1IChh5rDgCvnxPX8LgM9ZSw2eB4HtbGAyGgIbr-CfHLL-C20gnASvVfnXDc0QWfoywtdUylZskdXNH9Bp2aNP3VlO0gjs85DPJhM4za2IU2yWFQYjBUHFEttPrYC9xxOjv1LWjxiKkIqjNKyoMoEg4WausMXvbF-y0VE8kHNBiykwo8AkAnKMifxJp0e3Fg)?

Comment: @Holger: Ah, that's the reason why 2^20 rows and 2^14 columns are needed per sheet. But why does your example not fully using this size? Very pixelated ;-).